# c++ Playsound to specific output/device

Tags: c++, windows, audio

So I wanted to make a program that uses Playsound() to play an audio file to my speakers which looks more or less like this:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("sound.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

My problem is that it plays the sound not on my speakers, but my headphones which are set as default output so they receive system sound and anything undefined.

I already set the sound output of the file to my speakers in the windows sound config which works for all application except this one. So is there any way to play sound specifically on my connected speakers using Playsound()?

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the device PlaySound uses. It should always pick the default sound device.

> I already set the sound output of the file to my speakers in the windows sound config wich works for all application except this one.

What do you mean that you "set the sound output of the file". You can't choose devices for specific sound files. You can only choose which devices are preferred for sounds and a special bit for Communication apps like Zoom or Teams.

Make sure Control Panel has the device as both "Default Device" and "Default Communication Device". Right click on the output device in Control Panel to enforce this setting

[image]

Comment: "What do you mean that you "set the sound output of the file". You can't choose devices for specific sound files."
I meant the .exe file that runs my code as you can specify the outputdevice for every application like browsers, games, discord, etc.

Pretty unfortunate that I cant choose a device as I dont want my system sounds and every other standart program to also be on my speakers. But anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aromatic_Sand_4298 - now that I found that setting, let me see if I can figure something out...

Comment: @Aromatic_Sand_4298 - It appears that PlaySound will respect the Windows Settings (Volume->Sound->Volume Mixer) for a particular EXE and device. However, if you change the setting while the app is running, the application has to be restarted before the change will take effect.  Have you tried just restarting the app after making this change?

Comment: Yeah tried restarting the app multiple times already, but I can also try to restart my pc maybe that does something.

Comment: So I restarted my pc and still same problem as before, if PlaySound() doesnt work, is there another simple method for playing audio files that can accomplish what I need?

Comment: PlaySound basically just loads the entire sound file into a memory buffer, strips off the header, and invokes waveOutWrite to play it (assuming it's PCM. It it has a codec, it requires decompression).  That would work well if you sound file is short.